# DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_1 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable In Angular 13

Tags: datatables, angular-datatables, angular13

I have implemented jQuery Datatable Grid in Angular 13. But when I delete record and datatable is refreshed. then below error occurs.

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_1 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
```

Any Solution for this ??

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for many hours, I found solution for this.

just add   **`destroy:true`** in this.dtOptions = {} like below

```
 this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      scrollX: true,
      processing: true,
      deferRender: true,
      destroy:true
    };
```

Error will be fixed. Thanks

Comment: accept your answer to resolve the question. :)